# Download a file in shiny using base64 encoding (without downloadHandler)

Tags: r, download, shiny, base64, uri

I have a shiny application with the following main parts:

**ui.R**

```
actionButton("go", "Go")
tags$a("download")
```

**server.R**

```
observe({
  if(input$go==1){
    [... stuff generating a pdf file myfile.pdf ...]
    base64_pdf <- base64enc::dataURI(file="myfile.pdf", mime="application/pdf")
    updateActionButton(session, "go", "Download PDF")
    shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('$("#download").attr("href", "%s").attr("download", "myfile.pdf")', base64_pdf))
  }
  if(input$go==2){
    shinyjs::runjs('$("#download")[0].click()')
  }
})
```

This app works perfectly:

- I click on the "Go" button and a pdf file is generated
- this pdf file is converted to its base64 encoding
- this base64 string is sent to the attribute `href` of the `<a>` tag
- I click again on the button (whose label has been updated to "Download PDF") and this triggers the `<a>` tag: my pdf is downloaded.

Now, I have the same application except that instead of a pdf file, the app generates a html file with `rmarkdown`. Everything works except the download: when I click the second time on the button, it looks like the browser triggers an "infinite download": at first glance nothing happens, but when I close the browser, it asks me whether I want to cancel the download.

I tried to replace the html file with a small txt file and the download works. So it seems that the problem is the base64 encoding of the html. Is there a problem because this html already contains some base64 strings? Or why? I also tried to use `httpuv::encodeURIcomponent` to encode the file but the same problem occurs.  What could I do to download the html in such a way?

Comment: Hmmm... finally there's a simpler and better way, which does not require to base64-encode, by copying the file in the `www` folder or another resource folder set with `addResourcePath`.